# Typescript redux - Type '{ userInfo: any; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hey guys new to typescript here, especially with redux. As stated in the title, the issue pops up for the initialstate in my store. The top part of the error - `Argument of type '{ userLogin: { userInfo: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ userLogin?: undefined; }'`.

Store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { userLoginReducer } from "./user/reducer";



export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
});

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo")!)
  : null;

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

export const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

```
Argument of type '{ userLogin: { userInfo: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ userLogin?: undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'userLogin' are incompatible.
    Type '{ userInfo: any; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
const initialState: {
    userLogin: {
        userInfo: any;
    };
}
```

Reducer

```
import { Store } from "redux";
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGOUT,
  UserActionTypes,
} from "./types";

export const userLoginReducer = (state: Store, action: UserActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };

    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };

    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };

    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am writing this because i get the error with mostly code

Comment: Can you provide your `userLoginReducer` code as well? It seems like your initial state type is conflicting with the return type of that reducer

Comment: @Nick just edited

Comment: `state: Store` does not seem correct in the function signature for the reducer. You should create a type that specifies the correct shape of this part of your state object. It looks like it'll be something like `{ loading: boolean, userInfo: something, error: something }`

Comment: @Nick didnt work =(. I don't know where this ```userLogin?: undefined``` is coming from. Am i suppose to create a type for my userLoginReducer?

Comment: Can you please post the line number reference from the error as well? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @charlieb posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly type your `userLoginReducer` shape - `state: Store,` is incorrect as it will type the reducer's data to be a full-blown Redux store.

Generally though, I would recommend you take a step back from the code you are writing right now, as it is showing a very outdated type of Redux that we do not recommend any more (for years!) for new projects and that is especially annoying to use with TypeScript as it requires lots of extra code.

You might be following a very outdated tutorial.

I would recommend you to go through the official [Redux Essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) that will teach you Redux with Redux Toolkit (on a JavaScript level) and then go through the [Redux Toolkit TypeScript QuickStart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript). If you have any questions beyond that on how to use that with TypeScript, all the examples in the [Redux Toolkit Api Reference (here createSlice)](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) are available both in TypeScript and JavaScript.

As you can see, using TypeScript there requires just a few annotations here and there and does not require you to do stuff like creating union action types which at this point we kind of consider to be an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `combinereducers` so need to pass `initialvalue` when create `userLoginReducer`:

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage }, action: UserActionTypes) => {...}
```

You can read more in [createstore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#arguments)

> [preloadedState] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify
> it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to
> restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer
> with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape
> as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything
> that your reducer can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
`export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;`
is problematic because typescript has to jump through a lot of hoops to figure out what the return type of store.getState is. Since there is no interface or type that defines what the root state should look like, typescript is trying to determine what the root state's type is by looking at the initial state, which is not a complete picture of all possible values during the life of your app.

A good place to start would be to define an `interface` that defines the expected types in your entire store, and then reference that interface everywhere that you reference state like so:

```
interface RootState {
  userLogin: { loading?: boolean, userInfo: any },
};

const initialState: RootState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};
```

The above likely will not solve your problem, but it will likely cause typescript to give you a better error message, and will also set you up for success as you continue to build your app.

Comment: Actually, `type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>` is our official recommendation on how to do that. Yes, assuming your store is typed incorrectly it will break, but essentially things *should* break if your store is typed incorrectly since that points at a deeper problem.